# Oracle Stored Procedure is not working in SSRS Query Designer

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, reporting-services, plsql

I wrote a stored procedure in Oracle 11g. It has 4 input parameters and 60 output parameters. It executes successfully and returns output using GUI in Oracle SQL developer tool.

But problem is in SSRS I connect with Oracle as ODP.NET Data Source. Test connection succeeds in shared data set properties.

When I select the specific stored procedure and pass 4 input parameters which are VARCHAR2 Data types

[image: Input parameters Passing]

it shows an error:

[image: Wrong number or types types of argument in call to]

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the output parameters as well when you call the procedure.
PS: I don't like the idea of having 60 output parameters. I'd use a record or a collection (or both).